# Is there a way to view console output when testing an app on an ipad?

Tags: ipad

I am trying to debug an app I have made which uses an accessory which goes into the connector slot.  Therefore, if I want to test the app with the accessory, I cannot connect the iPad to my computer at the same time.  Some issues are arising and it would be nice to get some sort of feedback as to what is happening but without the connection to xcode I am blind.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When not connected to the debugger, your NSLog-ed messages go to device's console which you can see when you connect the device later and click on it's console tab in Xcode organizer.